# Transform queryset through a foreign key when target class isn't known

Tags: django, django-1.6

In my application I have a number of models structured like this:

```
class S(models.Model):
    i = models.OneToOneField(I, null = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
```

If `q` is a queryset returning `S` objects, I can construct a queryset returning the associated `I` objects like this:

```
I.objects.filter(s__in = q)
```

The challenge I now face is that I need generic code that can perform this operation for any `OneToOneField`. In other words I have to write code which given the queryset `q` and a variable `field_name` containing the name of the `OneToOneField` such as `'i'` in the above case can produce the new queryset.

I could iterate over the objects individually with:

```
for s in q.select_related(field_name):
    i = getattr(s, field_name)
    # Do something with i
```

However if the operation to be done with `i` involves calling `i.save` or `i.delete`, this becomes inefficient. So I am looking for a way to produce a queryset returning `I` objects such that I can invoke `.update` or `.delete` on the resulting queryset.

*What I have tried so far*

I found this construction which appears to work

```
def transform_queryset_through_one_to_one(q, field_name):
    related_field = getattr(q.model, field_name).field.related
    return related_field.parent_model.objects.filter(
        **{'%s__in' % related_field.var_name: q}
    )
```

My question now is: Is this the proper way to construct the desired queryset or is there a cleaner way to construct that queryset given only `q` and `field_name`?

Comment: I think passing a dict is exactly what you need. I don't think you should find a way to get all `reverse_field_name`, you can just build a static list or something to define them. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ShangWang A static list of names doesn't make sense, because it will be outdated as soon as another model is introduced. I'd much rather find the name of the reverse field in the proper way (I already know how to find the forward field).

Comment: @ShangWang Looks like `getattr(q.model, field_name).field.related.var_name` might be the string I am looking for.

Comment: You can be as hacky as possible, but it sacrifices a lot of readability. People won't know what are you doing in the above statement. Not to mention it's a "proper" way.

Comment: @ShangWang Readability isn't worth much if it causes the code to not do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @ShangWang I have updated the question with the best construction I found so far. So my question is, can `transform_queryset_through_one_to_one` be rewritten in a cleaner way while still returning the same query?

Comment: I misread your original post, I thought you try to find all `field_name` that is `OneToOne` relationship to your model `I`. I couldn't find a better way other than what you have, sorry about that.